# C# type of references (i,.e. "out" parameters) typeof(char &) or typeof(out char)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

For some library debugging usage I am developing a custom attribute which would be able to match existing methods.

For example the following:

```
[NetMethodAliasMethod("TryParse", Parameters = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(char)})]
```

...should match static bool `System.Char.TryParse (string? s, out char result)`. The attribute "Parameters" are tested against ParameterInfo.ParameterType  MethodInfo.GetParameters() to match  the parameters (of course name is matched as well).

In case of the `string?` this works because the nullable attribute is not part of the type. However the type returned from `MethodInfo` for the 2nd parameter is `char&`, while `typeof(char&)` is not allowed. Is there any possible way to pass this type ?

I was thinking about generic delegates, but see no way as the use of delegates is to be specific on which methods are compatible. Another Idea was to use `typeof(System.Char).GetMethod("TryParse")`. But this causes the same trouble if multiple overloads exist, where we would have to use `GetMethods` (with 's') instead and again match the parameter types.

Of course I could use string checking of the type names, but that should be the last resort if no other way is possible. But since `Type(char&)` exists, I hope there is a way to get it ?

Comment: `Type.MakeByRefType` is your friend for purposes of `GetMethod`, although this will not be allowed in an attribute. `MethodInfo.Invoke` meanwhile requires no special consideration, you can pass the base (non-ref) type (and the input array will be modified to copy the output value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make such a type by using the [`MakeByRefType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makebyreftype?view=net-6.0) method.

However you cannot actually call this method when writing your attribute, because something like `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()` is not an *attribute argument expression* (defined at the very bottom of [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#213-attribute-specification)).

Therefore, a workaround I would go for is to declare an additional parameter for your attribute that encodes where these "by refs" are:

```
public bool[] ParametersAreByRef { get; set; }
```

And then do:

```
[NetMethodAliasMethod(
    "TryParse", 
    Parameters = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(char)}
    ParametersAreByRef = new bool[] { false, true })]
```

Only when you retrieve the attribute later down the line, do you use `MakeByRefType` to recreate the `Type`s depending on the values in `ParametersAreByRef`.

```
var modifiedParameters = attribute.Parameters.Zip(
    attribute.ParametersAreByRef, (t, b) => b ? t.MakeByRefType() : t
).ToArray()
```

If you don't like passing `ParametersAreByRef` every time for methods with all non-by-ref parameters, you can make `Parameters` a positional parameter (put it as a constructor parameter), and then you can initialise `ParametersAreByRef` to `Parameters.Select(x => false).ToArray()` by default or something like that in the constructor.

As Jeroen Mostert suggested in the comments, another workaround is to use pointer types, seeing as they are very rare in actual code, to encode by-ref-ness:

```
Parameters = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(char*)}
```

When you retrieve the attribute instance, check `IsPointer` and use `GetElementType`:

```
var modifiedParameters = attribute.Parameters.Select(
    x => x.IsPointer ? x.GetElementType().MakeByRefType() : x
).ToArray();
```

You can also do this in the setter of `Parameters` if it has a backing field.

Alternatively, make your own dummy `ByRef<T>` type so that by-ref-ness can be annotated:

```
public abstract class ByRef<T> {}

…

Parameters = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(ByRef<char>)}
```

Then

```
// e.g. in the setter of Parameters
_parameters = Parameters.Select(
    x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ByRef<>) ? x.GetGenericArguments()[0].MakeByRefType() : x
).ToArray();
```

Comment: Another option is to use a placeholder wrapper like `abstract class ByRef<T> {}`, then something like `t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ByRef<>) ? t.GetGenericArguments()[0].MakeByRefType() : t`. (Pointer types and `.IsPointerType` could be used to eliminate the need for a separate type, as long as you're not planning on calling any method that takes pointers, which seems reasonable.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Pointer types work? I didn't expect that! I thought they are exclusive to `unsafe` contexts.

Comment: The use of pointer values is unsafe, but an expression like `typeof(char*)` is considered safe (since you're not yet doing anything that the runtime can't check).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I like the elegance of this solution and used it. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for your suggestion.  I must say that the ByRef<T> suggestion posted by JeroenMoster is more elegant IMHO. Nevertheless your solution is also a valid one, so my suggestion would be that you take over my answer below (or similar) base on Jeroen's comment as second solution in your answer and I will accept your post as final answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like the elegance of @JeroenMostert comment so I did add a ByRef abstract generic class to my attribute:

```
public abstract class ByRef<T> { };
```

and modified the Parameters property to resolve the type

```
private Type[]? _parameters = null;
public Type[]? Parameters
{
  get { return _parameters; }
  set
  {
    if(value==null)
    {
      _parameters = null;
      return;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<value.Length; i++)
    {
      Type type = value[i];

      if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ByRef<>))
      {
        value[i] = type.GetGenericArguments()[0].MakeByRefType();
      }

      _parameters = value;
    }
  }
}
```

This setter resolves all ByRef to T&

Note that in my case here, `Parameters` is nullable because I use null as parameter wildcard (i.e. matching any types and count).

Comment: Modifying the input array seems iffy -- it's technically legal and seems to work for attribute data without upsetting the runtime, but still. With LINQ you could do `set =>  _parameters = value?.Select(unwrapByRef)?.ToArray();`, with `Type unwrapByRef(Type type)` the logic in the check.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the wording in the spec suggests that the setter is called with the stored value at runtime, so it won’t upset the runtime in any way. I do think that this kind of complicated setter is quite rare in attributes, so it’s “iffy” in that sense.

Comment: @Sweeper: while it's nice that it works for attributes, my comment was more general -- if this was not an `Attribute` but any old class it would be very surprising for the caller that `instance.Parameters = myArray` ends up modifying `myArray`, and that should likely be considered a bug. Since the only caller here will be the runtime it's "OK", but since it's easily avoided, I'd just avoid it.